# (ffmpeg) Split internet radio stream into separate mp3 files of equal duration, which could be played separately

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, mp3

I want to build a software which listens to internet radio stations and analyzes them with echoprint.

In order to handle audio processing i decided to use ffmpeg.
I have URL of radio stream, which i want to split and save into separate files of same duration (about 30 seconds). I also need to concatenate back consecutive segments of stream into big mp3 file sometimes.

command for segmentation:

```
ffmpeg -i StreamURL -codec copy -f segment -segment_list segment_list.txt -segment_list_type flat -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp3
```

The problem is, that segment files are not pure mp3 file. 
Can ffmpeg segment stream into pure mp3 files and concatenate them back?

Comment: Do you want a MP3 without any metadata?

Comment: Yes, i need only audio itself

Answer (score 0):

The MP3 muxer writes both ID3 tags as well as a Xing header. Disable all of these.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i StreamURL -codec copy -f segment -segment_format_options "id3v2_version=0:write_id3v1=0:write_xing=0" -segment_list segment_list.txt -segment_list_type flat -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp3
```